# set IFRAME innerHTML property in silverlight

Tags: html, silverlight, iframe

I'm going to display HTML in my silverlight 4 application, I cannot use Out of Browser or windowless mode, in fact I'm reading emails using IMAP (WCF) and want to display their body in my Silverlight web application. I'm using an IFRAME to display html, it works fine, but I should set its URL to display HTML, is it possible to set its innerHTML instead of setting its URL? I have my body as HTML and I want to set it as IFRAME innerHTML, can I use Javascript to set its innerHTML property? how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this control.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx

This control dose not requires windowless = true and also works in browser. but it is only support html pages not a aspx pages.

Comment: you need to specify path of html file to read using StreamReader. there is a sample application also there in the link